# Setting up Hyper-V Server with Two Network Adapters

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I read in an article that it's best practice to have two network adapters for a Hyper-V server - where one network adapter is for the management and the other for the virtual machines.

Can I the two network adapters be on the same network/subnet or do I have to isolate them via separate network/switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can I the two network adapters be on the same network/subnet** or do I have to isolate them via separate network/switches?

Yes, they can be on the same subnet.  For security reasons, you may want to put your management NIC on a different, isolated VLAN/subnet that only your IT/operations machines have access to (and the same could be said for your managed switches, core routers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is good to follow, and separating your management and production networks is a great practice. In small enough environments it just isn't practical to separate things. That being said, they can be on the same network. If they're going to be on the same network I'd recommend bonding them together as long as your switch will support it.